# Como hacer peticiones del servicio a spring

Tags: angular, spring

Tengo el siguiente  servicio de angular, el cual lo quiero usar para obtener datos del backend:

**pero con el servicio que tengo, se ejecuta el console console.log('MENSAJE', this.http.get(http://localhost:8080/user));**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';



import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { from } from 'rxjs';
// import { Observable} from "rxjs";

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KJService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getUsers() {
    console.log('MENSAJE', this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/user`));
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/user`);
  }

  public getUsersSince(cont) {
  }
}
```

y en swagger de spring tengo este request que quiero utilizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no hace peticiones, cual es la falla?

este es el app-module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

NO tengo errores, solo que no obtengo los datos, en el console **console.log('MENSAJE', this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/user`));** obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

Comment: @JackNavaRow ahora me sale otro error

Comment: entonces esto te funciono?

Comment: si, pero sigo sin obtener los datos de backend

Comment: @JackNavaRow puse crossorigin y nada

Comment: ya eso es otra respuesta. deberias adaptar esta respiesta para dar la solucion y crear o buscar otra pregunta con tu error

Comment: @JackNavaRow ahora ya no obtengo errores, pero tampoco obtengo los datos, solo me muestra un observable

Comment: entonces ya esta listo

Comment: @JackNavaRow pero no se supone que debe retornar datos, espero un array

Comment: @JackNavaRow debo usar suscribes? algo parecido a esto?  this.CountryService.GetCountries()
    .subscribe(countries => {
        this.myGridOptions.rowData = countries as CountryData[]
    })

Comment: es lo ideal para eso usas angular

Comment: @JackNavaRow vengo de angularjs de hace mucho, y por eso tengo problemas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92308/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-hubman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente forma:

En el component.ts llamo a un .ts que es el que va a tener todas las llamadas al servidor:

```
constructor(private service: DataService){}

 ngOnInit() {
        this.fetchData();
 }

 private fetchData() {
  this.service.fetchDataManual().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                    this.originalParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                }, error => {
                    this.errorServer = true;
                    this.myMessage.message = "Fallo en la conexión con el servidor.";
                }
            );
 }
```

Y en el .ts que maneja las llamadas:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

fetchDataManual() {
    const url: string = "http://localhost:8090/ml/get/";
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
}
```

Tendrás que añadirlo en el app.module.ts como proveedor de datos:

```
 providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es' }, CookieService, DataService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Si necesitas más información ->
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: pero con el servicio que tengo, se ejecuta el console   console.log('MENSAJE', this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/user`));

Comment: haz el console.log dentro de la respuesta success de la llamada rest